# PHP preg match wrong capturing

Tags: php

I want to capture `<div class='troll'><goodTag/>trololoQWE</div>` (1)

and `<div class='troll'>trololo123</div>` (2)

and `<div class='troll'>besttrololo123</div>` (3)

but ignore `<div class='troll'><badTag/>trololoASD</div>` (4)

I tried this regexp: `/<div class='troll'>([^(<badTag\/>)].*?)<\/div>/`

but then I can capture only (2) :(

How to correctly ignore long text from first position of capture group ??

Edit: I want catch all content of this div, but ignore if first item is `<badTag>`

Comment: `[^(<badTag\/>)]` means: any character except `(`, `<`, `b`, `a`, `d`, `T`, `g`, `/`, `>`, and `)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following regex:

```
/(<div class='troll'>(?!<badTag\/>).*<\/div>)/
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mD6wG7/4)

Comment: Little patch: <div class='troll'>((?!<badTag\/>).*)<\/div> This is perfect match what I wanted to catch :)

Comment: I've just wanted to add it in case you want only text inside div without divs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
/<div class='troll'>((?!<badTag\/>).*)<\/div>/
```

Tested here:

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/69Y

Comment: This catching only last character of <div>...</div>

Comment: No, it's not. How do you test it?

Comment: Your site returns Array[0] == FullMatch; Array[1] == OnlyLastCharacterOfMatch;

Comment: Array[0] is what you're looking for, isn't it? Edit. Ok, you edited your question. Just add braces.

Comment: Actually it's enough to move last brace to the right. I've edited my answer to do what you mentioned in your edit.